# Probleman con PANDAS CSV - Función SHAPE

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estoy haciendo este ejercicio:

Debes utilizar Pandas para ingestar en un objeto Dataframe el contenido del archivo provisto
"Fuentes_Consumo_Energia.csv".
Esta función debe informar la cantidad de registros cuya entidad sean Colombia o México retornando
esos dos valores en una tupla de la siguiente manera (Colombia, México).
Pista averiguar la funcion Shape

```
import csv
from xml.dom.minidom import Entity
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def Ret_Pregunta01():
    df = pd.read_csv("datasets\Fuentes_Consumo_Energia.csv")
    colombia = df["Colombia"]
    mexico = df["México"]
    dfshape = df.shape
    nRows = dfshape[0]
    nCols = dfshape[1]
```

Esto es lo poco que pude hacer...

Comment: Dado que no nos adjuntas un acceso al fichero .csv, nos ayudaría a entender tu pregunta si con la función  df.info() nos muestras la estructura de la base de datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

**Nota:** Como no incluiste tus datos cree un `dataframe` genérico con los datos siguientes:

```
    Entidad     Col1    Col2
0   México      22      False
1   Colombia    51      True
2   Ecuador     21      True
3   Perú        33      True
4   México      26      False
```

Lo que pide el enunciado es filtrar todas las filas que contengan "México" o "Colombia" y luego obtener la forma del `dataframe` filtrado.

Para filtrar una columna con cualquiera de los elementos de una lista podemos utilizar [`pandas.DataFrame.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html)

```
df['Entidad'].isin(['México', 'Colombia'])
```

Y podemos utilizar la línea anterior para filtrar el `dataframe` original

```
df[df['Entidad'].isin(['México', 'Colombia'])]
```

Al imprimir la línea anterior obtenemos lo siguiente:

```
    Entidad     Col1    Col2
0   México      22      False
1   Colombia    51      True
4   México      26      False
```

Y por último podemos obtener la forma (Shape) de ese `dataframe` filtrado

```
df[df['Entidad'].isin(['México', 'Colombia'])].shape
```

Que en este caso devuelve `(3, 3)`, es decir, 3 filas y 3 columnas

La función quedaría así

```
def Ret_Pregunta01():
    return df[df['Entidad'].isin(['México', 'Colombia'])].shape
```

Pero yo la llevaría un paso adelante solicitando un argumento para indicar la columna, otro para indicar una "lista" con datos a filtrar y obtener `shape` como resultado

```
def Ret_Pregunta01(col, lista):
    return df[df[col].isin(lista)].shape
```

De esta forma si quisieras filtrar cualquier otra columna y lista podrías hacerlo como se muestra en los siguientes ejemplos:

```
[In:] Ret_Pregunta01('Entidad', ['Ecuador', 'Perú'])
[Out:] (2, 3)
[In:] Ret_Pregunta01('Col1', [21, 33, 26])
[Out:] (3, 3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Entendiendo que Colombia y México están en una columna, quizás te sirva este ejemplo.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Person":

                   ["John", "Myla", "Lewis", "John", "Myla"],

                   "Age": [24., np.nan, 21., 33, 26],

                   "Single": [False, True, True, True, False]})

Myla = df['Person'].value_counts()['Myla']
John = df['Person'].value_counts()['John']
tupla = (Myla, John)
tupla
```

Que nos devuelve

(2, 2)